# Unable to get basic implementation of Freemarker working

Tags: java, servlets, freemarker

I am trying to configure a Freemarker template from a Servlet like so:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;
@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    // class fields
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String views = "/WEB-INF/views/";

    public Controller(){

    }

    // used to handle any get requests i.e. webpage navigation
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.setClassForTemplateLoading(Controller.class, views);
        conf.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        Template indexTemplate = conf.getTemplate("index.ftl");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Map<String, Object> indexMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        indexMap.put("name", "Chris");

        try {
            indexTemplate.process(indexMap, writer);
        } catch (TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(writer);

    }
}
```

But I get the following error when I startup the Tomcat server:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webapp]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webapp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is the file structure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That error is irrelevant. It's basically a summary telling that deployment of `/webapp` failed, which you already know for long. You need to look further back in the server log to find the actual problem causing the deployment fail and then share it (or copypaste it into Google for answers if not already done yet).

Comment: Also, because it's the deployment that's failing, its reason can't be what's inside `doGet()`. Unless, you miss `freemarker.jar` from your deployment, which leads to a class linking error.